# My Apache localhost is not working - Forbidden

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am completely new to PHP and web servers. I have a test PHP file. When I run this in the terminal I can see that PHP is working "php /Users/Fryza/Sites/phptest.php"

When I type these into the web browser I get 403 Forbidden error:

```
http://localhost/~fryza/phptest.php

http://localhost/phptest.php
```

I have a file (/private/etc/apache2/users/fryza.conf) that has these contents:

```
<Directory "/Users/fryza/Sites/">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My DocumentRoot in private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf is /Users/Fryza/Sites/

I also have this directory /Library/Webserver/Documents - I used to have this as the document root but it wasn't working in this location either.

I have read through a bunch of stack overflow posts but they are not working for me.

The apache server definitely is running. PHP is working. Just can't get the files to load in the browser.

I'm running Mountain Lion

I did the same tutorial as the guy here and am having the same problem:
[403 Forbidden error when accessing localhost on Mac OS X10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750184/403-forbidden-error-when-accessing-localhost-on-mac-os-x10-8)

This is the error log:

```
[Mon Oct 28 17:57:17 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Oct 28 17:57:17 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Oct 28 17:57:17 2013] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Oct 28 17:57:17 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Oct 28 17:57:17 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Oct 28 17:57:17 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.26 mod_ssl/2.2.24   OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Access Log:
    ::1 - - [28/Oct/2013:18:05:38 -0700] "GET /~fryza/phptest.php HTTP/1.1" 403 220

Comment: Check access and error log.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't even access a plain HTML file either, from your document root? In other words, have you tried loading an index.htm or .html file?

Comment: Your access log shows `~fryza/` but your Apache config is targeting `\Users\fryza\Sites` which is probably equivalent to `~fryza/Sites`.  Have you tried `<Directory "/Users/fryza/">` and accessing `http://localhost/phptest.php`?  or trying before making any changes `http://localhost/Sites/phptext.php`?

Comment: jmbertucci - just made the change but getting the same problem

Comment: Hmm... if you httpd.conf docroot is set to `\Users\Fryza\Sites` and your permissions are set for that same directory and you're still getting permission issues, could it be that the Apache worker isn't allowed read access to that folder? What are the file permissions for that directory?

Comment: Permissions:
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Fryza  staff      0 Oct 28 18:08 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 Fryza  staff  29261 Oct 28 15:58 phpinfo.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Fryza  staff    185 Oct 28 16:07 phptest.php

Comment: Is [`mod_userdir`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) enabled?

Comment: zerkms I'm not sure how to use mod_userdir I dont see that or UserDir in the httpd file anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you are running skype, your localhost will not run because skype also use the port as localhost. but when you run localhost first before skype it will work.
but when skype run first, you must end task by pressing **ctr+alt+del** then **task manager** and **select skype** then **end task**..

but that's only for info..
the real deal here is how your localhost work..
try to do this.

click the icon of your **wamp server** on the **right bottom** of your computer..
then click **Restart All Services**..
And run your localhost.

That's all I know.. Im a newbie here.. tnx :)

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured it out. I don't know WHY this worked - but it did.

I changed my fryza.conf file from:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Can someone explain why this worked?